# needs corrections in writing a LL(1) math expression parser

Tags: antlr4

I tried to write a LL(1) math expression parser.
I tried to eliminate left-recursive and left common factor, and my grammar looks like the following:

```
grammar test;


NUM: 
LEFT_PAR? NEG? INT (DOT INT)? EXP? RIGHT_PAR? ;
fragment INT: [1-9][0-9]* | '0' ;
fragment EXP: [eE][+\-]? INT ;
fragment NEG: '-' ;
fragment DOT: '.' ;

FACTORIAL: '^' ;

ADD: '+' ;

SUB: '-' ;

MUL: '*' ;

DIV: '/' ;

MODULUS: '%' ;

LOGICAL_NEG: '!' ;

LEFT_PAR: '(' ;

RIGHT_PAR: ')' ;

COMMA: ',' ;

VAR_NAME: [A-Za-z0-9_.]+ ;

CEIL : 'CEIL' ;

FLOOR: 'FLOOR' ;

TRUNC: 'TRUNC' ;

SQRT: 'SQRT' ;

ABS: 'ABS' ;

EXP_FUNC: 'EXP' ;

LOG: 'LOG' ;

SIN: 'SIN' ;

COS: 'COS' ;

TAN: 'TAN' ;

MIN: 'MIN' ;

MAX: 'MAX' ;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;


math_expression:
math_expression_t math_expression_e_dash ;

math_expression_t:
math_expression_f math_expression_t_dash ;

math_expression_e_dash : 
 ( ADD | SUB ) math_expression_t math_expression_e_dash | /*epsilon*/ ;

math_expression_f:
math_expression_n math_expression_f_dash ;

math_expression_t_dash:
( MUL | DIV | MODULUS ) math_expression_f math_expression_t_dash | /*epsilon*/ ;

math_expression_n:
LEFT_PAR math_expression RIGHT_PAR | LOGICAL_NEG math_expression | NUM | SUB? VAR_NAME ;

math_expression_f_dash:
FACTORIAL math_expression_f | /*epsilon*/ ;
```

I tried to figure it out whether it's LL(1), by typing antlr4 -Xlog option in terminal.But the result from the log file didn't imply my grammar is good.

The result from the log file is shown as follows:

```
2022-11-08 16:57:33:896 semantics LogManager.java:25 tokens={EOF=-1, NUM=1, FACTORIAL=2, ADD=3, SUB=4, MUL=5, DIV=6, MODULUS=7, LOGICAL_NEG=8, LEFT_PAR=9, RIGHT_PAR=10, COMMA=11, VAR_NAME=12, CEIL=13, FLOOR=14, TRUNC=15, SQRT=16, ABS=17, EXP_FUNC=18, LOG=19, SIN=20, COS=21, TAN=22, MIN=23, MAX=24, WS=25}

2022-11-08 16:57:33:896 semantics LogManager.java:25 strings={'^'=2, '+'=3, '-'=4, '*'=5, '/'=6, '%'=7, '!'=8, '('=9, ')'=10, ','=11, 'CEIL'=13, 'FLOOR'=14, 'TRUNC'=15, 'SQRT'=16, 'ABS'=17, 'EXP'=18, 'LOG'=19, 'SIN'=20, 'COS'=21, 'TAN'=22, 'MIN'=23, 'MAX'=24}

2022-11-08 16:57:33:899 LL1 LogManager.java:25 
DECISION 0 in rule math_expression_e_dash
2022-11-08 16:57:33:899 LL1 LogManager.java:25 look=[{3..4}, {2..7, 10}]
2022-11-08 16:57:33:899 LL1 LogManager.java:25 LL(1)? false
2022-11-08 16:57:33:899 LL1 LogManager.java:25
 
DECISION 1 in rule math_expression_t_dash
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 look=[{5..7}, {2..7, 10}]
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 LL(1)? false
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 

DECISION 2 in rule math_expression_n
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 look=[4, 12]
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 LL(1)? true
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 

DECISION 3 in rule math_expression_n
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 look=[9, 8, 1, {4, 12}]
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 LL(1)? true
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 

DECISION 4 in rule math_expression_f_dash
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 look=[2, {2..7, 10}]
2022-11-08 16:57:33:900 LL1 LogManager.java:25 LL(1)? false
```

The log above seems to show that e_dash,t_dash,and f_dash have problems in look ahead symbol and can't make it LL(1).
I wonder how can I correct my grammar to make it right in LL(1),thank you.

Comment: Something like this change: `e : t ep ; ep : ( '+' | '-' ) t ep | ; t : f tp ; tp : ( '*' | '/' ) f tp | ; f : p fp ; fp : '^' p fp ;p : NUM | '(' e ')' | ('-'|'+') t;`. Also, do not add `LEFT_PAR`, `RIGHT_PAR` or `NEG` in your NUM lexer rule. Let the parser deal with this. Otherwise, a prescription for a disaster.

Comment: I don't think what you try is possible. Expressions are, much more like any other language construct, highly recursive, which requires often longer lookahead. Alternatively, you could limit your expression to a very simple syntax, to accomplish what you want.